# Java - I get an error when i try to use a box layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I was trying to create a frame using a box layout but I get a strange error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared.
```

here's the portion of code in my Jframe class that's probably causing the error:

```
    JLabel JL = new JLabel();
    PongPanel pp = new PongPanel();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    setLayout(layout);
    panel.add(pp);
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    panel.add(JL);
    add(panel);
```

Comment: Cut & paste your error messages into Google or search SO.  You'll learn that you aren't the first: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=exception%20in%20thread%20%22awt-eventqueue-0%22%20java.awt.awterror%3a%20boxlayout%20can%27t%20be%20shared&safe=active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target container been assigned to the `panel` container in this statement

```
BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
```

Use a different layout manager instance for the parent container replacing

```
setLayout(layout);
```

with

```
panel.setLayout(layout);
```

Read: [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)